# How to convert multiple lists into one dataframe

Tags: r

I have a list that tells you how many possible mates an individual has. It looks like this:

list:

```
$`A1`
[1] "D2" "E2" "F2" "H2"
$`B1`
[1] "G2" "I2" "J2" "K2" "L2"
$`C1`
[1] "J2" "M2" "N2" "O2" "P2"
[6] "Q2" "R2" "S2"
```

So for example, the possible mates of individual A1 are individual D2, individual E2, individual F2, and individual H2.

I want to turn this into a data frame that pairs up an individual to its possible mates. So I want something like this:

df:

```
Female ID   Mate ID
       A1        D2    
       A1        E2
       A1        F2
       A1        H2
       B1        G2
       B1        I2
       B1        J2
       B1        K2
       B1        L2
       C1        J2
       C1        M2
       C1        N2
       C1        O2
       C1        P2
       C1        Q2
       C1        R2
       C1        S2
```

Answer (score 5):

I like `purrr:map_df` for this problem:

Your data

```
L <- list(A1 = c("D2", "E2", "F2", "H2"),
    B1 = c("G2", "I2", "J2", "K2", "L2"),
    C1 = c("J2", "M2", "N2", "O2", "P2", "Q2", "R2", "S2"))
```

Solution

```
library(purrr)
map_df(L, ~data.frame("Mate.ID" = .x), .id="Female.ID")

   # Female.ID Mate.ID
# 1         A1      D2
# 2         A1      E2
# 3         A1      F2
# 4         A1      H2
# 5         B1      G2
# etc
```

I like `map_df` because of the useful `.id` argument that attaches the name of the list-entry.

(This can also be written...)

```
map_df(L, function(i) data.frame("Mate.ID" = i), .id="Female.ID")
```

(...the `.x` is shorthand for `function(i) i`)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It looks like it works! Although I get this error: "## Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
## Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): binding character and factor vector,
## coercing into character vector"
Is this something to be worried about?

Comment: Not really. It simply lets you know that it had to convert the example data to characters (from factors) before binding. If you start with a dataset that is characters (rather than factors), this warning will not show.

Answer (score 3):

One solution using just base R:

```
mylist <- list(A1=c("D2", "E2", "F2", "H2"),
            B1=c("G2", "I2", "J2", "K2", "L2"),
            C1=c("J2", "M2", "N2", "O2", "P2", "Q2", "R2", "S2"))

mydf <- lapply(1:length(mylist), function(i) {
    data.frame(`Female ID`=names(mylist)[i], `Mate ID`=mylist[[i]], stringsAsFactors=F, check.names=F)
})

mydf <- do.call(rbind, mydf)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stack` from base R -

```
L <- list(A1 = c("D2", "E2", "F2", "H2"),
    B1 = c("G2", "I2", "J2", "K2", "L2"),
    C1 = c("J2", "M2", "N2", "O2", "P2", "Q2", "R2", "S2"))

result <- stack(L)
names(result) <- c("MaleID", "FemaleID")

result

   MaleID FemaleID
1      D2       A1
2      E2       A1
3      F2       A1
4      H2       A1
5      G2       B1
6      I2       B1
7      J2       B1
8      K2       B1
9      L2       B1
10     J2       C1
11     M2       C1
12     N2       C1
13     O2       C1
14     P2       C1
15     Q2       C1
16     R2       C1
17     S2       C1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> L <- list(A1 = c("D2", "E2", "F2", "H2"),
          B1 = c("G2", "I2", "J2", "K2", "L2"),
          C1 = c("J2", "M2", "N2", "O2", "P2", "Q2", "R2", "S2"))

> library(tidyverse)
> library(plyr)

> ldply(L, data.frame) %>%
  set_names("Female ID", "Mate ID")

   Female ID Mate ID
1         A1      D2
2         A1      E2
3         A1      F2
4         A1      H2
5         B1      G2
6         B1      I2
7         B1      J2
8         B1      K2
9         B1      L2
10        C1      J2
11        C1      M2
12        C1      N2
13        C1      O2
14        C1      P2
15        C1      Q2
16        C1      R2
17        C1      S2
```